# HVAC selection software

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, windows-7, windows-8

Is there a free HVAC selection software (or catalog) for hospitals on windows? Like the software that HVAC resellers and shopes have.

Comment: *(Someone asked me for it, that's his only requirement, I don't know much about HVAC so I'll leave the question as is)*.

Comment: Like for what? Calculating required air-flow? Determining what tonnage unit based on cubic feet? What size duct-work is to be used? How many returns to install?

Comment: @Raystafarian yes i think stuff like that cause the person who asked for it is a thermodynamic engineer, and a mechanical engineer, so what you described is his job, he asked me to get him something like the hvac selection software by carrier, so i don't know what to choose, I'd appreciate a list of all plausible software, I'll give it to him and he then would pick the one that he may need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend starting with [this ACCA approved list](https://www.acca.org/standards/approved-software).

> ACCA is a non-profit association whose membership includes more than
>   60,000 professionals and 4,000 businesses in the indoor environment
>   and energy services community. We work together to promote
>   professional contracting, energy efficiency, and healthy, comfortable
>   indoor environments.

The list includes (among others) -

- [Wrightsoft](http://www.wrightsoft.com/)
- [Elite](http://elitesoft.com/)
- [Adtek](http://www.adteksoft.com/)
- [Avenir](http://www.avenir-online.com/AvenirWeb/HeatCAD/HeatCADHome.aspx)

I also found duct planning software at http://www.plandroid.com/

Comment: are these software free?

Comment: @Lynob no, but I'd say your best bet would be looking for software alternatives to those specific applications. It might be sort of difficult to find something so specialized for free unless there's like a sketchup add-on or something.